# How application domain can be useful in exception handling?

Tags: .net-4.0, appdomain, applicationdomain

I know little bit about the concept of application domain. We can delete the appdomain to unload the dll.
Is it possible to use appdomain for better exception handling? How it can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know loading modules in child `AppDomains` will not offer better exception handling. In the MSDN page for [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) it remarks that:

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, this backstop for
>   unhandled exceptions in child threads was removed, because the
>   cumulative effect of such silent failures included performance
>   degradation, corrupted data, and lockups, all of which were difficult
>   to debug.

This means that an unhandled exception in a child thread even if the code is executed in a child AppDomain, will bring the whole process down.

Usually child `AppDomains` are used for the assembly unload feature that you mention, and for executing code in a sandbox (restricted security environment).